# Size class for UILabel inside UITableView randomly ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have an `UITableView` with custom cells which contain `UILabels`. The text size of labels should be different on iPhone and iPad, so I set different fonts for regular size classes [in interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMZ3Q.png).

The problem is that sometimes on iPad font size is not respected and `UILabel` is displayed with small text size (the one from iPhone). Also, the font size for regular size class is [ignored randomly for some table view cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8D60.png).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use this code to identify device size:

```
 #define iOSVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

+(NSString*)deviceSize {

CGFloat screenHeight = 0;

if (iOSVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(@"8")) {
  screenHeight = MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
}else
  screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

if (screenHeight == 480)
  return "Screen 3.5 inch";
else if(screenHeight == 568)
  return "Screen 4 inch";
else if(screenHeight == 667){
  if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 2.9) return Screen5Dot5inch;
    return  "Screen 4.7 inch";
}else if(screenHeight == 736)
  return "Screen 5.5 inch";
else
  return "UnknownSize";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, specifying fonts according to size classes is not reliable. What I often do is set the font size to the size that fits the largest size class i.e. iPad, and then downscale the font in autoshrink to  a scale that caters to the smallest size class i.e iPhone.

Comment: I had a similar issue, to which I kept the font size for iPad by default and used size classes for iPhone (I had to use it for iPhone Portrait and Landscape separately, since there is no single size class that defines "all iPhones in portrait and landscape" together). @Szymon Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Actually I'm setting fonts sizes for iPad from code and it works the best. @stuti I'd love to try your solution in the near future.

Comment: @stuti looks like your solution works just fine. Thanks.